# How to make a function of MAE and RAE without using library(Metrics)?

Tags: r, function, statistics

My goal is to create functions of Mean Absolute Error (MAE) and Relative Absolute Error (RAE) without using any kind of library, like library(Metrics).

I try to input a formula inside a function for both MAE and RAE

```
mae <- function(a, b)
{
    mean(abs(a, b))
}


rae <- function(a, b)
{
    abs(a,b )
}
```

However, both function provide different answer compare to the function below,

```
library(Metrics)
stats <- function(a,b)
    {
        mae <- mae(a,b)
        rae <- rmse(a,b)
    }
```

Comment: See `Metrics`' implementation : `Metrics::rae` and compare it to theory. Not sure why your functions take one input?

Comment: I think it's a conceptual issue. Look at the definition of [MAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error) for instance. Your `mae` function uses `abs` but doesn't really do any subtraction.

Comment: @NelsonGon. The input is already edited. Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is wrong. You can use the following function to calculate `mae` and `rae` without any package

```r
x <- c(1.1, 1.9, 3.0, 4.4, 5.0, 5.6)
y <- c(0.9, 1.8, 2.5, 4.5, 5.0, 6.2)

mae1 <- function(x,y)
  {
  mean(abs(x-y))
  }

mae1(x, y)
#> [1] 0.25


rae1 <- function(x,y)
  {
  sum(abs(x-y))/sum(abs(x - mean(x)))
  }

rae1(x,y)
#> [1] 0.1666667

library(Metrics)
#> Warning: package 'Metrics' was built under R version 3.6.2

mae(x, y)
#> [1] 0.25
rae(x,y)
#> [1] 0.1666667
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It is giving same output as that of `Metrics` package.

## Update

If your data contains NAs then the above functions, as well as the functions of package `Matrics`, will fail. Under such situation use the following code

```r
x <- c(1.1, 1.9, 3.0, 4.4, 5.0, 5.6, NA)
y <- c(0.9, 1.8, 2.5, 4.5, 5.0, 6.2, 2)

mae1 <- function(x,y, na.rm=TRUE)
  {
  mean(abs(x-y), na.rm=na.rm)
  }

mae1(x, y, na.rm=TRUE)
#> [1] 0.25


rae1 <- function(x,y, na.rm=TRUE)
  {
  sum(abs(x-y), na.rm=na.rm)/sum(abs(x - mean(x, na.rm=na.rm)), na.rm=na.rm)
  }

rae1(x,y, na.rm=TRUE)
#> [1] 0.1666667

library(Metrics)
#> Warning: package 'Metrics' was built under R version 3.6.2

mae(x, y)
#> [1] NA
rae(x,y)
#> [1] NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I tried the function, yet it provides different answer compare to the function with library(Metrics).

Comment: Now you try with some data provided in my answer. It is giving same output as that of `Metrics` package.

Comment: In order to avoid conflict between `Metrics` package functions and newly created functions, I have defined the `mae1` and `rae1`.

Comment: @HYDR0GEN Now see my update for datasets containing NAs.