# how to do the mean absolute error (mae) on two dataframes with NaN in r

Tags: r, dataframe, nan, equation

My data looks like this:

```
> dput(head(df1,25))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16644, 16645, 16646, 16647, 
16648, 16649, 16650, 16651, 16652, 16653, 16654, 16655, 16656, 
16657, 16658, 16659, 16660, 16661, 16662, 16663, 16664, 16665, 
16666, 16667, 16668), class = "Date"), AU = c(0.241392906920806, 
0.257591745069017, 0.263305712230276, NaN, 0.252892547032525, 
0.251771180928526, 0.249211746794207, 0.257289083109259, 0.205017582640463, 
0.20072274573488, 0.210154167590338, 0.207384553271337, 0.193725450540089, 
0.199282601988984, 0.216267134143314, 0.217052471451736, NaN, 
0.220703029531909, 0.2164619798534, 0.223442036108148, 0.22061326758891, 
NaN, 0.277777461504811, NaN, 0.200839628485262)), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> dput(head(df2,25))
structure(list(UF1 = c(0.2559, 0.2565, 0.257, 0.2577, 0.2583, 
0.259, 0.2596, 0.2603, 0.2611, 0.2618, 0.2625, 0.2633, 0.2641, 
0.2649, 0.2657, 0.2665, 0.2674, 0.2682, 0.2691, 0.27, 0.2709, 
0.2718, 0.2727, 0.2736, 0.2745), UF2 = c(0.2597, 0.2602, 0.2608, 
0.2614, 0.2621, 0.2627, 0.2634, 0.2641, 0.2648, 0.2655, 0.2663, 
0.267, 0.2678, 0.2686, 0.2694, 0.2702, 0.2711, 0.2719, 0.2728, 
0.2737, 0.2745, 0.2754, 0.2763, 0.2773, 0.2782), UF3 = c(0.2912, 
0.2915, 0.2918, 0.2922, 0.2926, 0.293, 0.2934, 0.2938, 0.2943, 
0.2947, 0.2952, 0.2957, 0.2962, 0.2968, 0.2973, 0.2979, 0.2985, 
0.2991, 0.2997, 0.3003, 0.3009, 0.3016, 0.3022, 0.3029, 0.3035
), Date = structure(c(16644, 16645, 16646, 16647, 16648, 16649, 
16650, 16651, 16652, 16653, 16654, 16655, 16656, 16657, 16658, 
16659, 16660, 16661, 16662, 16663, 16664, 16665, 16666, 16667, 
16668), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to do the MEAN ABSOLUTE ERROR (mae) between the ***observed*** values `df1$AU` and ***predicted*** values `df2$UF1`, `df$UF2` and `df$UF3` using the following code ([How to make a function of MAE and RAE without using library(Metrics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499222/how-to-make-a-function-of-mae-and-rae-without-using-librarymetrics?rq=1)):

```
mae1 <- function(df1$AU,df2$UF1, na.rm=TRUE)
  {
  mean(abs(df1$AU-df2$UF1), na.rm=na.rm)
  }

mae1(df1$AU,df2$UF1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

but I always get this error:

```
Error in mean.default(abs(df1$AU - df2$UF1),  : 
  object 'na.rm' not found
```

I also tried to do with `library(Metrics)`

```
mae(df1$AU, df2$UF1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

but always get this error

```
Error in mae(df1$AU, df2$UF1,  : 
  unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

I tried to do only:

```
mean(abs(df1$AU-df2$UF1), na.rm=TRUE)
```

and I got a value, but I don't know if corresponds to the real "mae" value.

Note:

1. My data as `NaN`
2. I think this error may be related to `na.rm` error instead of the `mae` function but I couldn't solve it anyway.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `df1$AU` and `df2$UF1` as function arguments, use, say, `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
mae1 <- function(o,p,m=T) {
  mean(abs(o-p),na.rm=m)
}

mae1(df1$AU,df2$UF1)
[1] 0.03733099
```

Note: your function should work as well, I don't know why you are getting these errors.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I got this errors: ```Error in mean.default(abs(df1$AU - df$UF1),  : 
  object 'm' not found
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"```. Also, I try to find a solution when ```na.rm``` doesn´t function but no success.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I got this additional information:  ```exists("na.rm")``` and I got this:
```[1] FALSE```

Comment: @CláudioSiva You are doing something wrong, did you paste and execute the code that I provided exactly as is? Are you calling the function mae1?

Comment: I replicate exactly your example

Comment: @CláudioSiva Then there is probably something wrong with your environment. Reset your R environment (clear all variables) and try again.

Comment: did that and got the same errors again

Comment: @CláudioSiva Are you sure that you ran the mae1 function properly? Type `mae1` in the console and paste the exact output here.

Comment: the errors associated with the 1st comment doesn't allow the creation of ```mae1```

Comment: @CláudioSiva There is something wrong with your environment then. Try creating a simpler function without any arguments, to see if you can even do that. Then progressively add arguments and check when it breaks down.

Comment: I've reinstalled R and have the same problems. Even when I try with smaller datasets. Maybe is something wrong with the code, I don't see other justification.

Comment: I tried ```mean(abs(df1$AU-df2$UF1), na.rm=TRUE)``` and got the same output as you ```[1] 0.03733099```.

Answer (score 0):

Base R Solution:

```
# Extract the required vector names in a list:
# req_vec_names => list of vector names
req_vec_names <- list(
  act_vec_name = "AU",
  pred_vec_names = grep(
    "UF\\d+",
    c(
      colnames(df1), 
      colnames(df2)
    ),
    value = TRUE
  )
)

# Function to create the mean absolute error:
# mae => function()
mae <- function(actual_vec, pred_vec){
  return(
    mean(
      abs(actual_vec - pred_vec),
      na.rm = TRUE
    )
  )
}

# Calculate the mean absolute error: 
# maes => named double vector
maes <- vapply(
  req_vec_names$pred_vec_names,
  function(x){
    mae(
      as.double(df1[,req_vec_names$act_vec_name]),
      as.double(df2[,x])
    )
  },
  double(1)
)

# Print result: named double vector => stdout(console)
maes

#UF1        UF2        UF3 
#0.03733099 0.04024130 0.06848576
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but the code doesn't work. I keep getting this error: ```Warning message:
In mean.default(abs(actual_vec - pred_vec), na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA```

Comment: @CláudioSiva you're columns (vectors) are of the wrong data-type, try the ammended code above.

Comment: I keep getting errors: ```Error during wrapup: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart``` maybe something wrong with R I don't know.

Comment: @CláudioSiva there will be nothing wrong with R. If you take the dataset you provided and run the code I wrote it will give you the correct answer. Your data-types are incorrect. It appears you have a list object that you are trying to coerce to a double.

Comment: I'm getting the same error even using the dataset I've provided. ```Error in mean(abs(actual_vec - pred_vec), na.rm = TRUE) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'```

Comment: @CláudioSiva clear your variables and re-try I just did ran the code using your provided data.frames and it worked fine.

Comment: I reinstalled R and try it again and got the same errors.

Comment: @hello_fiend could you please provide me what was your output result?

Comment: @CláudioSiva please see edit displaying the output from my R console.